# Dynamically creating directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create template dynamically. When I inject the hard coded value through directives attribute it works fine. But when I assign it using angular variable it does not seem to work. Below is the js code

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.customer = {
  name: 'Naomi',
  address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
};
$scope.nameTempl = 'customer-name.html';
$scope.addressTempl = 'customer-address.html';
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
return {
  templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
    return attr.type;
  }
};
});
})(window.angular);
```

this is html part

```
<body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<div my-customer type="{{nameTempl}}"></div>
<div my-customer type="{{addressTempl}}"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Instead of using variables if i directly use values  it seems to be working fine.

I dont understand why is this happening?
[Plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sa5CbZlbbkbYzTDIOpzB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that angular first process the template and then the DOM. So when he gets to the attr.type, it's still {{nameTemp1}}, angular has yet manipulated the DOM. My suggestion is, try to pass the address in another way. [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FceQ4E7ZHbtfnLUWud70?p=preview) shows how you can try creating a service that would hold an object, and then bind the url to the object. Then, inject the service to the directive and use the url. Just make sure to put an "ng-if" on the directive the checks if the scope had created that object and bound it to the service's object

Here is the service

```
service('service', [function() {
    return {
      template: {}
    };
  }])
```

And this is the controller:

```
controller('Controller', ['$scope', 'service', function($scope, service) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
    $scope.addressTempl = 'customer-address.html';
    service.template.url = $scope.addressTempl;

  }])
```

and the directive looks like this:

```
directive('myCustomer', function(service) {
    return {
      templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
        return service.template.url;
      }
    };
  })
```

Comment: i want to change the template source by changing the associated value. Through service i can only instantiate once which will not be beneficial in my case.

Comment: as I explained, you cannot access this in the directive. if you pass a key to your directive, you can do service.template[key]... that how you can choose a specific template by passing values to the directive

Answer (score 0):

You can use different templates as follows:

Live example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E886EetZCImg1eMgTTY2?p=preview).

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
  $scope.nameTempl = 'customer-name.html';
  $scope.addressTempl = 'customer-address.html';
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      type: "@",
      customer:"=myCustomer",
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="type"></div>'
  };
});
})(window.angular);
```

And html part

```
<body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
   <div my-customer="customer" type="{{nameTempl}}"></div>
   <div my-customer="customer" type="{{addressTempl}}"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: actually I am trying to replace ng-include with directive. as ng-include is slow. Hence this solution kills the purpose.

Comment: In this case, you will need to specify in question of your assignment directives. Give an example of when to use `ng-include` vulnerability degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access scope in templateURL function however there is a way to load template at run time. Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/n20Sxq?p=preview

```
app.directive("cellItem", ["$compile", '$http', '$templateCache', '$parse', function ($compile, $http, $templateCache, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope , element, attrs) {

              scope.$watch(attrs.template, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                  loadTemplate(value);
                }
              });

              function loadTemplate(template) {
                  $http.get(template, { cache: $templateCache })
                    .success(function(templateContent) {
                      element.replaceWith($compile(templateContent)(scope));                
                    });    
              }
            } 
        }
    }]);
```

Hope this solve your issue.